# Как обновить token c retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit

На текущий момент от сервера приходит предупреждение о необходимости обновить токен в хедере запроса. Токен можно обновить отправив запрос на обновление токена используя рефрештокен.
Каким образом корректно обрабатывать данную ситуацию?

Добавить Intereceptor? Но тогда в нем придется [хардкодить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630788/5417750) похожим стилем.

Проблема красивее не решается так как на клиент он вешается в момент его непосредственного создания, а для красивого решения уже нужен клиент.

Добавить Authenticator? Можно - но это отдельный роут на ошибку 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему созданием `Intercepter` и `Authenticator` навесив в них зависимость от "альтернативного" `ApiService`. С помощью `dagger` и аннотации `@Named` это делается довольно просто. 
Логика внутри самих `Intercepter` и `Authenticator` достаточно проста и действительно сводится к простой проверки нужных условий.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы отправляете запрос на сервер, а сервер вам возвращает ответ, в котором указано,что нужно обновить токен. Тогда, мне кажется будет правильно(если вы используете архитектуру MVP), нужно передать данный параметр(что токен нужно обновить) во View, и во View уже его обработать.

Ну и во View пишите:

```
if(params.equals("Need Refresh Token"){
  RefreshTokenPresenter refreshPresenter = new RefreshTokenPresenter();
}
```

Comment: `equels`?) `if` не закрыт чет